# Power Apps: Table Mapping Only works with Associated View

Tags: dataverse, powerapps-modeldriven

I have two Tables: Customer and Payments.

The Customer has Details such as First Name, Last Name, Address, etc.

Payments has the Last Name, First Name, Payment and Payment Date.

I created a 1:N relationship between Customer and Payments i.e. A Customer can have many Payments. I made the Last Name of payments a Lookup to Customer. In addition, I went to Classic View and did a Mapping between the Customer First  Name and Payments First Name.

Here is what I observed:

1. If I create a payment using the Payment Associated View the First Name gets populated automatically along with the Last Name. So all I need to do is enter a payment and it looks right. See record 1 in screenshot 1.

[image]

2. If I create a payment directly in its main form (Last Name in Payment is a lookup from Customer and First Name is a read only with mapping set), the First Name is not populated. See record 2 in screenshot 1 and screenshot 2. Is there a way to correct this?
   [image]